# AlpineJS custom magic doesn't get defined

Tags: webpack, alpine.js

bundle.js

```
import Alpine from 'alpinejs'
import clipboard from './clipboard'

window.Alpine = Alpine
Alpine.plugin(clipboard)

Alpine.start()
```

clipboard.js as described here https://alpinejs.dev/advanced/extending#bundle-module

```
export default function (Alpine) {
  Alpine.magic('clipboard', () => {
    return (text) => {
      const decodedText = unescape(text.replace(/\\u/g, '%u'))
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(decodedText)
    }
  })
}
```

yet, this code is giving me an error saying `ReferenceError: $clipboard is not defined`:

```
<div x-data>
  <a class="cursor-pointer" @click="$clipboard('a string')">
    <svg... copy icon />
  </a>
</div>
```

can't figure out whats wrong.

I have even tried putting this in the bundle instead of a plugin() call.

```
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  console.log('init')
  Alpine.magic('clipboard', () => ({
    copy(text) {
      return () => {
        const decodedText = unescape(text.replace(/\\u/g, '%u'))
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(decodedText)
      }
    },
  }))
})

Alpine.start()
```

Comment: It works perfectly for me (I've used *browserify* with *esmify* to generate bundle.js)

Comment: Interesting... Will have to experiment more to see if I can find a cause. We use webpack

Comment: Fwiw, I tried to get this running without a build system - with just script tags - and I get the same error as you.

Comment: I also tried with *webpack* and everything works.
The only problem is that *navigator* can only be used with HTTPS sites, but in Chrome, setting your local site in the whitelist you can proceed anyway.